# git pull request not updating diff in new file

Tags: git, git-push, pull-request

I have been working on my local repo on a file. I made changes to it. Committed to my local and made a pull request to origin/master.

Before it was merged into the origin. I found out that one particular file was fine the way it was before. ie no changes were required.

The next thing I did was to git checkout -- [filepath] to the original copy.

I then added and committed (nothing really to commit) and pushed it upstream.

When I went to check the differences it still says that I have made changes to the file when I expected there to be no changes.

Can someone point out where I went wrong?

Comment: `git show <SHA>` should give some clues to changes that went in that commit

Comment: Please add the exact output of `git status /path/to/your/file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally your "merge" might have reference your files has changed on your commit, even if you have reset it after (and commit again).